# sails.js alternative of print <%- %> text?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

i am using sail.js MVC. in view mode i am printing text with

```
 <%-"some text" %>
```

Is there any alternative method available ?

for example

```
<% print("some text"); %>
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the template string interpolation syntax?

Comment: The hard thing i don't want close the tag for print the HTML tags...

Answer (score 0):

`print` statement isn't defined on neither EcmaScript nor node (out of the box).

Sails defines their view string interpolation syntax like you have shown. However, if what you want is add a debug statement, then you can try adding `console.log('this is my debug msg')` where appropriate.

Also, instead of `<%- "some text" %>` you might want to try `<%= "some text" %>`

Another option is to set your sails project to work with handlebars, so you could do the following:

`<div>{{obj.value}}</div>` pretty much like mustache (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/283)

If what you want is being able to iterate through a list, you can use handlebars as follows:

```
<ul>
  {{#each items}}
  <li>{{agree_button}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: No... i mentioned print for a sample. see if i want to print some text with ternary condition i cant do it with <%- %>. All the server side script languages has some function like echo(PHP), Response.Write(ASP.Net).....

Comment: @balaphp you can't and you shouldn't. The point of Sails is that's an MVC framework and having logic in the view breaks that separation. In most modern MVC frameworks, the view is as "dumb" as possible only for display purposes, all the logic is done at the controller level.

Comment: i agree..But in some cases we have to print the data with in for loops. that time i don't want to close the node tag for printing.

Comment: @balaphp I have added how to iterate through a list in my answer above. That should help.